# Jacobian General::ivar issue

Tags: equation-solving, functions, procedural-programming

I have a differential equation labelled by `eq0` and I want to use finite-difference method to solve it. First, I have to set up the system of equations `eqn[i]` through a `For` function. Next, I have to calculate the Jacobian of the coefficient matrix of the system of equations for Newton's method. The parameter `n` labels the number of equations (or the grid points).

When I calculate the Jacobian up to `n=8` there is no problem, but beyond that, say `n=10` I encountered an `General::ivar` issue. I tried calculating the Jacobian using the derivative `D` function but I encountered the same issue so I guess maybe there is something wrong with how I wrote the code. Any hints?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
f = 1 - (z[x]/zh)^(d + 1);
L = Sqrt[1 + (z'[x]^2/f)]/z[x]^d;(*Lagrangian*)
eulageq = EulerEquations[L, z[x], x];(*Euler-Lagrange equation*)
s = Solve[eulageq, z''[x]][[1]] // Simplify;(*2nd order EOM*)
eq0 = z''[x] - s[[1, 2]] /. {d -> 3, zh -> 10};


(*Setting up the nonlinear system of equations*)
a = 0;
b = 1;
n = 10;
h = (b - a)/(n + 1);
alpha = 95/10;
beta = 10^-3;
z[0] = alpha;
z[n + 1] = beta;
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, eqn[i] = Simplify[Collect[eq0 /. {z''[x] -> ((z[i + 1] - 2 z[i] + z[i - 1])/h^2), z'[x] -> ((z[i + 1] - z[i - 1])/(2 h)), z[x] -> z[i]}, z[i]]]; Print["eqn[", i, "] = ", eqn[i]]]

j = 0;
x[0] = Table[(1 - i) alpha, {i, 1/10, 90/100, (90/100 - 10/100)/(n - 1)}]; 
xr[j] = MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Array[z, Length[Table[i, {i, 1, n}]]], x[j]}]; 
DFx = ResourceFunction["JacobianMatrix"][Table[eqn[i], {i, 1, n}], Table[z[i], {i, 1, n}]] /. xr[j]//N

General::ivar: 1/1000 is not a valid variable.
General::ivar: 171/20 is not a valid variable.
General::ivar: 8.55` is not a valid variable.
General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation.
JacobianMatrix [{73.26472605,46.03916874,45.22798136,47.78091888,53.1565758,61.92990427,75.89993511,419.515069,262284.3839,-226.5003625},{8.55,7.705555556,6.861111111,6.016666667,5.172222222,4.327777778,3.483333333,2.638888889,1.794444444,0.95}]

(*Jacobian using D function*)
DFx1=D[Table[eqn[i],{i,1,n}],{Table[z[i],{i,1,n}]}]/.xr[j]//N

During evaluation of In[222]:= General::ivar: 1/1000 is not a valid variable.
During evaluation of In[222]:= General::ivar: 171/20 is not a valid variable.
During evaluation of In[222]:= General::ivar: 8.55` is not a valid variable.
During evaluation of In[222]:= General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation.
\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({{8.55`, 7.705555555555556`, 6.861111111111111`, 6.016666666666667`, 5.1722222222222225`, 4.3277777777777775`, 3.4833333333333334`, 2.638888888888889`, 1.7944444444444445`, 0.95`}}\)]\({73.26472605314348`, 46.039168736484946`, 45.22798135742989`, 47.78091887685099`, 53.156575796563885`, 61.92990426583507`, 75.89993511371034`, 419.51506904343574`, 262284.38392592594`, \(-226.5003624756579`\)}\)\)
```

Comment: Is this BVP different of that discussed and solved with `NDSolve` on  https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42244/wrong-boundary-conditions-result-using-wavelet-collocation/42260#42260 ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev It's the same, however, I'm using a different method (finite-difference) to study this BVP since I'll eventually use the best method to study the harder BVP case similar to [275496](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275496/highly-coupled-nonlinear-second-order-differential-equations). I know you've resolved some other BVP issue with wavelet technique but, it doesn't seem to work in the simple case like this. Using shooting method somehow works for the simpler case but I think finite-difference may have an advantage for the harder case for big calculations.

Comment: You are right, with FDM this problem can be solved as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a small correction we can compute solution using `FindRoot` as follows

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
f = 1 - (z[x]/zh)^(d + 1);
L = Sqrt[1 + (z'[x]^2/f)]/z[x]^d;(*Lagrangian*)
eulageq = EulerEquations[L, z[x], x];(*Euler-Lagrange equation*)
s = Solve[eulageq, z''[x]][[1]] // Simplify;(*2nd order EOM*)
eq0 = z''[x] - s[[1, 2]] /. {d -> 3, zh -> 10};


(*Setting up the nonlinear system of equations*)
a = 0;
b = 1;
n = 250;
h = (b - a)/(n + 1);
alpha = 95/10;
beta = 10^-3; Z = Array[z, {n + 2}];
z[1] = alpha;
z[n + 2] = beta; rul = 
 Table[{z''[x] -> ((z[i + 1] - 2 z[i] + z[i - 1])/h^2), 
   z'[x] -> ((z[i + 1] - z[i - 1])/(2 h)), z[x] -> z[i]}, {i, 2, 
   n + 1}];
eqs = Table[eq0 /. rul[[i]], {i, Length[rul]}];



DFx = ResourceFunction["JacobianMatrix"][eqs, 
   Table[z[i], {i, 2, n + 1}]];



x[0] = Table[(1 - i) alpha, {i, 1/10, 90/100, (90/100 - 10/100)/(n)}];

sol = FindRoot[eqs, Table[{z[i], x[0][[i]]}, {i, 2, n + 1}], 
  Jacobian -> DFx, MaxIterations -> 1000, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

Visualization

```
ListLinePlot[Z /. sol, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure1]

Using code from my answer [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42244/wrong-boundary-conditions-result-using-wavelet-collocation/42260#42260) we can compute solution for inverse function $x(z)$ as follows

```
Clear[f, x, z]

f = 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
L = (Sqrt[1 + (x'[z]^(-2)/f)]/z^d) x'[z];(*Lagrangian*)
eulageq = EulerEquations[L, x[z], z];(*Euler-Lagrange equation*)
s = Solve[eulageq, x''[z]][[1]] // Simplify;
eq0 = x''[z] - s[[1, 2]] == 0;

eq1 = eq0 /. {zh -> 10, d -> 3};

zs = 95/10; z0 = 10^-3; sol2 = 
 NDSolveValue[{eq1, x[zs] == 0, x[z0] == 1}, x, z]
```

Finally we compare `sol` and `sol2` in one plot

```
Show[Plot[sol2[z], {z, 10^-3, zs}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "x"}], 
 ListPlot[Table[{z[i] /. sol, xx[[i]]}, {i, n + 2}], 
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Nice rewrite of the code, I just have one question. Now, instead of using the Jacobian for the Newton's method, you used the Jacobian in `FindRoot`. From the documentation, it stated that without the Jacobian `FindRoot` will do extra evaluations for finite differences. Does this mean that `FindRoot` is using finite difference method internally without specifyng it that specific method? Also, is there some specific reason why you made a shift in the index from `i=0` to `i=1` and `i=n+1` to `i=n+2`?

Comment: In addition to your code `sol`, I would like to construct an interpolating function to be substituted back to the Lagrangian and integrate in the domain `[x0,xf]` (calculate the action). I wrote `solution = Join[{z[1]}, Table[sol[[i, 2]], {i, 1, Length[sol]}], {z[n + 2]}]; zfunc = Interpolation[solution, InterpolationOrder -> 3]` but `zfunc[x]` produces an `InterpolatingFunction::dmval` issue. Why?

Comment: Actually, array `Z` should be defined before computation. As usual I use origin 1. If you like to use origin 0, just put `Z=Array[z,n+1,0]`, and then rewrite code. Concerning `FindRoot` , please, note, that  option `Jacobian ->J`  is described in tutorial  in section Options.

Comment: Use `xx = Range[a, b, h]; lst = Table[{xx[[i]], z[i] /. sol}, {i, n + 2}]; zsol = 
 Interpolation[lst]`;